# LiveCode Rounded Stack Corners

Tags: livecode

I'm mucking around with Livecode and I'm aware that we can use a gif or png to change the shape of a stack.

I don't want to change the stack shape, I just want the stack to have rounded corners across Mac, Windows and Linux.  I can't seem to find anything about this.  Does anyone know of an external or an elegant hack?

Answer (score 1):

You can always modify the rect of the underlying image, and (re)set the rect of the stack (pseudo):

```
set the rect of image "yourRoundRectImage" to newRect
set the windowShape of stack "yourStack" to the ID of image "yourRoundRectImage"
```

You may have to fiddle with the loc of the stack, since setting the windowShape does not always track the loc of the image within the stack itself. But all the properties are always available.

Answer (score 0):

Check up on the "windowShape" property in the dictionary. If you create an image with rounded corners, you can set the property of your stack to that image ID.

When you say you "do not want to change the stack shape", I assume you mean its overall width and height. Is that so?

Comment: I'm just trying to create a stack which has rounded corners but which can be resized.  What I meant to say originally is that I'm not looking to create a bizarrely shaped stack which is static (this I can do).  Back in the day I was pretty sure I could make the stack chrome render the mac toolbar even if it was on Windows.  Seems like it's an automated process but I really want to maintain the rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack though.

1. You create a new RectangleGraphic object from the toolbar. Set its style to "roundRect", set the roundRadius property to whatever you want. Set the size to your target size.
2. Use the command "import snapshot from rect (rect of the RectGraphic) of the RectGraphic" to create an image object. The reference to it is saved in the 'it' variable.
3. Do what dunbarx suggested and set the windowShape property to the ID of the newly created image.
4. Now the stack has the desired shape. Just clear up the previous objects by setting the visible of the RectangleGraphic to false (or delete it) and the same with the image object.

The stack now has rounded borders. Unfortunately, this new stack shape cannot be resized. Each time that you want to resize it, you repeat all steps by modifying the size of the graphic object in step 1 to the desired target size and follow again the process.

I really wish the Stack had more properties to customize its appearence but sadly it doesn't.

Check http://newsletters.livecode.com/may/issue70/newsletter3.php?id=NW70S38853 for further infor and ideas. The .gif file illustrates the process.

[image: Example taken from]